# Checking how many times a number has been entered

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm trying to solve one of the questions on a task sheet I've received, to help me further in my understanding of C++ code from my class.

It kept showing `100000` in output after I entered the values. Where is that `1` coming from?

I know there are better ways to write code for this but I just want to know were is my problem.

The question is
(and I quote):

Write a program that:

```
Asks the user to enter 10 numbers between 1 and 5 into an array and displays the array on screen.
Creates a second array of size 5 and fills it with zeros.
Counts how many 1s, 2s, , … 5s have been entered into the first array and stores this number in the second array.
Displays the second array as shown in the example below.
```

Code:

```
int A1[10];
int A2[5] = { 0,0,0,0,0 };
int count = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
here:
    cout << endl << i + 1 << "- enter a number between 1 and 5 for value : ";
    cin >> A1[i];
    if (A1[i] < 1 || A1[i]>5)
    {
        cout << "eror! enter a number between 1 and 5!";
        goto here;
    }
    
}


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
    {
        if (A1[i] = j)
        {
            A2[j - 1]++;
            break;
        }
    }

}


for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout << A2[i];
```

Comment: You should have a very good reason to use `goto`. I'm not sure such a reason exists. In your case there's no good reason for the use of spaghetti code; It should be changed to something like `cin >> A1[i]; while(A1[i] < 1 || A1[i] > 5) { cout << "error! enter a number between 1 and 5!\n"; cin >> A1[i];}`

Comment: Suggestion: Turn your compiler's warning levels higher and pay attention to them, even if the code compiles anyway. MSVC at /W4, or Clang or GCC with -Wall, would have given you a heads-up about the mistake here.

Comment: Unrelated: You'll freak out fewer people if you control when you increment `i` a little better and write the `goto` out. `goto` is harder to get right than it looks, and even when you do get it right, it is even harder still to prove to people that you did get it right. I've found it almost always takes less time to rewrite code without the `goto` than it does to explain and defend the `goto`. In this case, a `do`/`while` loop that repeats until good input is provided  inside the `for` loop should shut everyone up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend that you use `goto:`, it creates spaghetti code. you can put an `i--` in your error clause, like so:

```
int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    cout << i + 1 << "- enter a number between 1 and 5 for value : " << endl;
    cin >> temp;
    if (temp >= 1 && temp <=5)
        A1[i] = temp; 
    else
        i--;  
}
```

Also, if you want to compare 2 values, you should use the `==` operator. that is what's causing the problem in your second loop

like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
  for(int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
    if(A1[i] == j)
      A2[j-1]++;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

The error is on the row 21 or 22, you are using a single `=` which is the assignment sign, inside the if statement, so you are overwriting the value of `A[i]` to the value of `j`, but want to check if the element of `A[i]` is equal to `j`... So you have to add a `=` in the if statement.

Comment: The entire inner `for` loop and `if` are both unnecessary and could be replaced with `A2[A1[i] - 1]++;`.